# Api to api duplex connection

Tags: c#, api

So, I've got two Api and currently I'm using Rabbitmq for sending messages, but the problem is i need a console application to listen for the rabbitmq because an api can't do that. Is there any tool that can solve this? or is there a rabbitmq feature i didn't know?